# What does the syntax @VERSION@ mean in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I assume it's some sort of variable substitution, but I can't find any documentation on it.

I tried google searches and searches of this site.  But I think the '@' is causing problems.

Comment: Probably some templating like https://github.com/foundweekends/giter8 `sbt new` that generates `build.sbt`. It seems not to substitute a version. Where did you get this?

Comment: Here: https://github.com/zio/zio-config/blob/master/docs/index.md

Comment: It's docs templating - your code example when published looks like this: https://zio.dev/zio-config/ . There is no unusual Scala syntax in resulting snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's from sbt plugin `zio-sbt-website`

https://zio.dev/zio-sbt/#zio-sbt-website

https://github.com/zio/zio-sbt/tree/main/zio-sbt-website

https://search.maven.org/artifact/dev.zio/zio-sbt-website

And as we can see in its [build.sbt](https://github.com/zio/zio-sbt/blob/main/zio-sbt-website/build.sbt#L1)

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scalameta" % "sbt-mdoc" % "2.3.7")
```

it uses another sbt plugin `sbt-mdoc` using Scalameta's mdoc

https://scalameta.org/mdoc/

> Extensible
>
> Define custom variables like `@VERSION@` or programmatically implement custom modifiers to render tailor-made documentation for your project.

https://scalameta.org/mdoc/docs/installation.html

> We process the markdown with one of the following mdoc integrations:
>
> - **sbt-mdoc**: for usage with sbt projects.
> - command-line: to run from the console outside of a build tool.
> - library API: for programmatic usage.

> Configure site variables like `@VERSION@`
>
> Use `--site.VARIABLE=value` to add site variables that can be referenced from markdown as `@VARIABLE@`.
>
> ```
> coursier launch org.scalameta:mdoc_2.12:2.3.7 -- \
> +  --site.SCALA_VERSION 2.12.17
> ```

https://scalameta.org/mdoc/docs/why.html

> Why mdoc?
>
> - variable injection: use variables like `@VERSION@` to that make sure the documentation stays up-to-date with new releases.

https://github.com/scalameta/mdoc

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalameta/mdoc

https://github.com/scalameta/mdoc/tree/main/mdoc-sbt

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.scalameta/sbt-mdoc

So it's basically Scalameta :)